# Progressbar doesn't show up when list of tasks are running

Tags: c#, task, progress-bar

I have a TextBox that I can enter a series od ID separated by ",".
When I press a button, it will search the image in database according to the id and region name,
then finally save the image to disk. Everything is working, however the progressbar only shows up after all the Tasks get finished. How can I fix this problem?

```
private Task OutputImageProccess(string str){
//Here I have an image and data to be set in other window
MyImageWindow myWindow = new MyImageWindow();
myWindow.ImageTitle = str;
myWindow.CountryName = region;
..
//a method to save the image rendered in ram to save to disk
SaveImage(bmp, str);

return Task.FromResult(0);
}

private void SaveImage(RenderTargetBitmap bmp, string str)
{
   BitmapEncoder encoder;
   encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
   encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
   string folderName = OutputImageFolderTb.Text.ToString();         
   Directory.CreateDirectory(lktfolderPath + @"\" +folderName);
   string file = lktfolderPath + @"\" + folderName + @"\" + str + ".png";
   using (Stream stm = File.Create(file))
   {
       encoder.Save(stm);
   }
}


private async Task LoopAsync(List<string> strList, string region)
{
    List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var str in strList)
    {
        listOfTasks.Add(OutputImageProccess(str, region));
    }

    Task t = Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
    await t;
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finished");
        EditProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
}


//Button click to start the proccess//
 private async void OutputImageBnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    EditProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

    string region = ((ComboBoxItem)OutputRegionComboBox.SelectedItem).Content as string;

    string str = OutputImageTextBox.Text.ToString();

    strList = str.Split(',').ToList();

    await LoopAsync(strList, region);

    EditProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
 }
```

Comment: This seems a bit like https://stackoverflow.com/q/61984119/3107892. Maybe this can help?

Answer (score 1):

Your progress bar isn't being updated because there's nothing in that code that is actually asynchronous. You have an `OutputImageProccess` method that returns a `Task`, but it's not asynchronous; it just does its work synchronously and then returns an already-completed task.

To make this properly asynchronous, use asynchronous database and file APIs. Then your `OutputImageProccess` method (should be `OutputImageProcessAsync`) will use `await` and `async` instead of `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: Hello Stephen,But how do I add OutputImageProccess method to a list of Tasks if this method not return a Task?Since I need a list of OutputImageProccess Tasks to complete, then the progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;

Comment: Once you use asynchronous database and file APIs, then `OutputImageProcess` will become an `async Task` method.

Answer (score 0):

An `await` is not always a point in code where you really need to wait. It is possible that the task you are waiting on is already completed. In this case the `await` just unwraps the result and immediately continues without interruption.

A form has a single thread with an event loop where all sorts of events are added, button clicks, mouse moves and paints. It's in the paint event that the window calculates the layout and show it to the user. If you have a button click and in that event you add an element to the form and remove it, then it is gone for the next paint event and it will never appear on the screen.

This is also one of the reasons that you can get a 'not responding' form. This is because the time between paint events is too long and you can't see any updates on the screen. This is one of the reasons that 'async/await' was invented so the method can be (on the background/state machine) be split up in shorter methods leaving time for all the other events.

You can use tricks like `await Task.Yield()` so you can force the rest of the code to be scheduled on the event loop. But also know that CPU intensive work that has no influence on the form should better be moved to a separate thread (e.g. `await Task.Run(() => CpuIntensiveMethod());`) so you don't have to do tricks like insert useless 'breakpoints' with `Task.Yield()`.